# "You and I both know full well" = 「二人ともよく知っている」?

Tags: grammar, translation, words

I'm writing a section of a relay manga for Hokkaido University's Manga Research Society.

How you do you express "You and I both know full well..." and "our actual skills" in formal お嬢様っぽい Japanese?

I have translated it from:

"You and I both know full well that our strength isn’t physical fighting.  You really don’t want me to hurl such a heavy encyclopedia at such a pretty face, now, do you?  So instead of that, let’s compete by using our actual skills."

as:

> 「運動能力には、私たちは運動が得意ではない、二人ともよく知っているでしょうね。こんなに重い百科事典を、そんなにきれい顔に投げ付けさせることをしたくありませんね。その代わり、実績のスキルでバトルしましょうよ。」

Is 運動競技 or 実戦 better than 運動能力?
Is another word more suitable than 実績?

Comment: So they're not good at "physical fighting", right? What exactly are their "actual skills"?

Comment: One girl's skill is making the hairstyle "pompadour," and the speaker's skill is "romance novels" which I interpreted to mean writing them rather than just liking to read them.  These skills were picked by others participating in the relay about 女子力

Comment: わかっている ＞ 知っている.  A very common mistake among J-learners.

Comment: @seijitsu Then how about... お互いの([真]{しん}の)実力 or お互いの[得意技]{とくいわざ}?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about... あたくしたち二人とも、運動?(>> physical fighting = [喧嘩]{けんか}? or [殴]{なぐ}り合い?)が得意でないことは、お互いに充分承知のはずですわ。あなただって、こんなに重い百科事典をその可愛らしいお顔に投げつけられるのはお嫌でしょう？それより、実力?(>> our actual skills = ??)で勝負いたしませんこと？

Comment: 御嬢様言葉>>>> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VY5uI2Zzvi4 My favorite hehehe